# Trouble with imported data

Tags: export, import, output-formatting, interpolation, data

I have a multivariable function, I want to produce the data of that function, export the data and use the data for later purposes. However, the imported is not recognized as data.  Here is an example:

```
f[x_,y_,z_]=x*y*z;
data=Table[{{x,y,z},f[x,y,z]},{x,1,2,1},{y,1,2,1},{z,1,2,1}];
```

The output is:

```
{{{{{1, 1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1, 2}, 2}}, {{{1, 2, 1}, 2}, {{1, 2, 2}, 4}}}, {{{{2, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2, 1, 2}, 4}}, {{{2, 2, 1}, 4}, {{2, 2, 2}, 8}}}}
```

The format I need is {{x,y,z},f[x,y,z]}. So for this, I Flatten the data:

```
data//Flatten[#,2]&
```

here is the output:

```
{{{1, 1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1, 2}, 2}, {{1, 2, 1}, 2}, {{1, 2, 2}, 4}, {{2, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2, 1, 2}, 4}, {{2, 2, 1}, 4}, {{2, 2, 2}, 8}}
```

Until now everything is perfectly working, and I can interpolate this data. I want to save this data for later use and interpolate it in my future works. Therefore, I export it:

```
Export["mydata.csv", data//Flatten[#,2]&]
```

In the next step I import the exported data and the problem appears here. Here is the imported the same data:

```
{{{1, 1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1, 2}, 2}, {{1, 2, 1}, 2}, {{1, 2, 2}, 4}, {{2, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2, 1, 2}, 4}, {{2, 2, 1}, 4}, {{2, 2, 2}, 8}}
```

As you see, it is exactly similar to the exported data.

I try to interpolate the imported "mydata.csv". However, it gives this error:

```
Interpolation[Import["mydata.csv"], InterpolationOrder-> 1]
```

```
Interpolation::indat: Data point {{1, 1, 1},1} contains abscissa {1, 1, 1}, which is not a real number
```

I know that everything is related to the way I am exporting. I tried to define a format for exported data, such as "Table" and "Data", but it did not work. My main purpose is to interpolate data and I need it to be in the format of {{{x1,y1,z1},f[x1,y1,z1]},{{x2,y2,z2},f[x2,y2,z2]},... }.

I will be very appreciative if someone helps me.

Comment: `data = data // Flatten[#, 2] &;
Export["mydata.csv", data];
Import["mydata.csv"]`

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. So, already did it. Now I want to interpolate the imported "mydata". It gives me this error: ```Interpolation::indat: Data point {{1, 1, 1},1} contains abscissa {1, 1, 1}, which is not a real number```

Comment: What is the version of your Mathematica? In ver 13.0.1, `f=Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1]` correctly produces the interpolating function: `{(f @@ #[[1]]), #[[2]]} & /@ data` gives  {{1,1},{2,2},{2,2},{4,4},{2,2},{4,4},{4,4},{8,8}}.

Comment: I think there is a better way, but try `Interpolation[ToExpression@Import["mydata.csv"], InterpolationOrder-> 1]` and compare `Head/@ToExpression@Import["mydata.csv"][[1]]` with `Head/@Import["mydata.csv"][[1]]` (giving, respectively, `{List, Integer}` and `{String, Integer}`)

Answer (score 1):

This is how actually the data looks like after the export/import sequence, therefore the error message when trying to use the Interpolation function:

```
data = {{{{{1, 1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1, 2}, 2}}, {{{1, 2, 1}, 2}, {{1, 2, 2}, 
4}}}, {{{{2, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2, 1, 2}, 4}}, {{{2, 2, 1}, 
4}, {{2, 2, 2}, 8}}}};
Export["data.csv", data // Flatten[#, 2] &];
imported = Import["data.csv"];
imported  // InputForm
```

> {{"{1, 1, 1}", 1}, {"{1, 1, 2}", 2}, {"{1, 2, 1}", 2}, {"{1, 2, 2}", 4}, {"{2, 1, 1}", 2}, {"{2, 1, 2}", 4},
> {"{2, 2, 1}", 4}, {"{2, 2, 2}", 8}}

You can simply use [ToExpression](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) in order to get a list of integers:

```
ToExpression /@ imported // InputForm
```

> {{{1, 1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1, 2}, 2}, {{1, 2, 1}, 2}, {{1, 2, 2}, 4}, {{2, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2, 1, 2}, 4},
> {{2, 2, 1}, 4}, {{2, 2, 2}, 8}}

```
ToExpression /@ imported // Interpolation[#, InterpolationOrder -> 1] &
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Flatten[...,n] command.

```
f[x_, y_, z_] = x*y*z;
data = Flatten[
   Table[{{x, y, z}, f[x, y, z]}, {x, 1, 2, 1}, {y, 1, 2, 1}, {z, 1, 
     2, 1}], 2];
```

will produce

{{{1, 1, 1}, 1}, {{1, 1, 2}, 2}, {{1, 2, 1}, 2}, {{1, 2, 2},
4}, {{2, 1, 1}, 2}, {{2, 1, 2}, 4}, {{2, 2, 1}, 4}, {{2, 2, 2}, 8}}

I guess this format is what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But, my question is not this. The question is that after exporting this data and importing back, I can not Flatten the data or, I can not interpolate the data.

Comment: You need to clarify in more specific way what you want, what you have tried and how it failed....

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I edited my question. So, I do what you are doing. Then I export "mydata". Then I import it. In the later step, I want to interpolate "mydata". However, Mathematica gives this error: ```Interpolation::indat: Data point {{1, 1, 1},1} contains abscissa {1, 1, 1}, which is not a real number.```